# PHP walk all possible routes of an array

Tags: php, recursion, associative-array

I have a fairly simple problem, that i'm hoping you can help me with :)

I have an array:

```
-transport
--plane
---boeing
---airbus
--car
---audi
---ford
```

The array may have more levels with varying depth, but I need to output every route from the top layer. Something like:

```
transport->plane->boeing
transport->plane->airbus
transport->car->audi
transport->car->ford
```

Dose anyone have any suggestions how to approach this?

Many Regards
Andreas

Comment: Recursion, it's already a tag on the question. Try it out and when you have a problem, come back.

Comment: And on that note, check the manual for such keywords: *walk*, *array*, *recursive*. Oh look - [`array_walk_recursive()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <?php

function show($arr, $prefix = '')
{
    if (!is_array($arr))
    {
        if ($prefix)
        {
            echo $prefix . '->'. $arr, "\n";
        }
        else
        {
            echo $arr, "\n";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        foreach ($arr as $key => $val)
        {
            $pre = $prefix;

            if (is_array($val))
            {
                if ($pre)
                {
                    $pre = $pre . '->' . $key;
                }
                else
                {
                    $pre = $key;
                }
                show($val, $pre);
            }
            else
            {
                show($val, $pre);
            }
        }
    }
}

$list = array(
    'transport' => array(
        'plane' => array(
            'boeing',
            'airbus',
        ),
        'car' => array(
            'audi',
            'ford'
        ),
    ),
);

show($list);
```

output:

```
transport->plane->boeing
transport->plane->airbus
transport->car->audi
transport->car->ford
```

Comment: @JasonMcCreary, ok, I will change it.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary, I've changed my code, feel better now. Thank you.

Comment: Read about [recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion#Recursion_in_computer_science).

Answer (score 0):

You need to run a recursive array walker.

```
function walk_array($array) {
   foreach ($array as &$item) {
     if (is_array($item)) {
       walk_array($item);
     } else {
       echo $item;
     }
   }
}

walk_array($somearray);
```

The thing is, you need to re-use the same function from itself. But you should post more about your code, because normally you should be more controlled over your data structure.

Answer (score 0):

> any suggestions how to approach this?

[`array_walk_recursive()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php).

Set `user_data()` accordingly to remember the parent element.

**Note:** I have intentionally not provided sample code in an effort to teach you to fish. That is learn to check the manual and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $arrTrans = array(
        'plane' => array('boeing', 'airbus'),
        'car' => array('audi', 'ford')
    );
    $strTree = '';
    foreach($arrTrans as $strKey => $arrMode) {
        $strTree .= $strKey;
        foreach($arrMode as $intKey => $strVal)
            $strTree .= ' ' . $strVal;    
        $strTree .= PHP_EOL;
    }
    print $strTree;
?>
```

That should give some ideas